# Export for youtube: video shot with iPhone 14 promax with filmic pro log v3 4k 10 bit HEVC10 and Davinci resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am editing a video which shot in `iPhone 14 pro max` using `Filmic Pro`, `4k-10 bit`, `HEVC10`, `30 fps`.

I colour grade the video using `Davinci resolve 18.5`.

While doing the color grading, it is showing nice output in the screen. But when I upload it in youtube and preview there, the colour looks dull. I am giving the Davinci settings and screenshots from edited video played in mac and played in youtube given below

**Davinci Settings**

[image]

**Played in VLC player mac**

[image]

**Played in youtube**

[image]

As clearly visible in the pictures, the output are different with less saturated in youtube. How can I fix this issue??

Please help. Thanks in advance.